# matplotlib tests headless and without warning

Tags: python, matplotlib

I usually test my Python packages with [pytest](https://pytest.org/)

```
pytest
```

If the tests contain [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) plotting routines, windows will pop up that I have to close manually. To prevent that, I usually run the tests headless, either by invoking pytest with

```
MPLBACKEND=Agg pytest
```

or by setting

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

in the test file. Both variants generate the warning

```
UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
    plt.show()
```

which I'd rather avoid. The flood of agg-warnings might hide actual warnings that I care about.

Perhaps there's another canonical way of running matplotlib tests headless. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

In pytest, there are multiple ways for ignoring warnings, see [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-warnings.html). One possibility is to ignore the warning on individual tests by decorating the functions with

```py
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings(
    'ignore:Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.:UserWarning'
)
```

If you want to ignore *all* such warnings in the project, add

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
filterwarnings = [
  'ignore:Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.:UserWarning'
]
```

to your `pyproject.toml` or

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore:Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.:UserWarning
```

to your `pytest.ini`.